# What is the JavaScript equivalent of Ruby's "unless"?

Tags: javascript

Ruby has a handy [unless](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-unless) conditional, which is "The negative equivalent of if."

Is there a way to do a "negative if" in JavaScript that's more semantic than `if (!condition)`?

Comment: More semantic?  You mean defining a function that returns negated logic?  Like `if (checkForNegative(args) ) { /* stuff */ }`

Comment: No there isn't.

Comment: Why would I want to type 6 characters when 1 will do (and is the same across many languages)?

Comment: @ryanyuyu by semantic I mean something along the lines of "reads more like English": `unless(squareHasFourSides)`

Comment: in the context of a loop, `if ... continue` comes close. But then, this also exists as a concept in ruby (`next`).

Comment: That's an idealistic question. Idealistic version of JavaScript is CoffeeScript!

Comment: `unless` is **not** a method in Ruby. It's a **keyword**, like `if`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the hack :P

```js
let unless = (condition,callback)=>{!condition && callback();}
let a = 10;
let b = 20;
unless(a > b,()=>{console.log("A should be greater than B")})
```

Answer (score 7):

No, there's no such control structure. One thing you can do to make code more readable is wrap the negation in a function.

```
 function baconIsTooThin () {
    return !baconIsChunky();
 }

 if (baconIsTooThin()) { 
   ...
 }
```

Or you may want to use [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), which makes JavaScript look more like Ruby (and has `unless`) and compiles down to plain JavaScript.

[Example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:unless%20(foo)%20%0A%20%20alert(%27bar%27)):

```
// CoffeeScript
unless (foo) 
  alert('bar')

// Compiled JavaScript
if (!foo) {
 alert('bar');
}
```

Edit 2022: Don’t use CoffeeScript, it didn’t catch on and no one uses it these days. JS still does not and likely never will have `unless`.

Comment: "One thing you can do to make code more readable is wrap the negation in a function." - that's ... ugly. Don't do this please.

Comment: @djechlin as soon I saw it, my hand went for the downvote button, but then again the rest of the answer is ... correct.

Comment: Haha, well it's hard to think of a good example function name at 5:00 on Friday afternoon. Feel free to edit. :)

Comment: "Didn't catch on" or "nobody uses it these days" doesn't mean anything. Programming is not a fashion show. If something meets your quality standards, you can use it, regardless of whether there are two other users or a million.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such statement in JavaScript. I believe this construct comes close:

```
a || (_ => {
    console.log('a is false');
})();
```

```js
let a = false;
a || (_ => {
    console.log('a is false');
})();
```

Obviously this has no practical importance unless you want to make your code less readable. A normal `if (!a)` is the way to go, or -- in second place -- `if (a); else`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other solution :

```
const itsColdToday = false;

if (!itsColdToday) {
  console.log("You don't need a coat today");
}
```